# Is it possible to use a SQL Server backup and link it to Visual Studio 2012 or you need the .mdf file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, mdf

I have a SQL Server backup from my server and I have a comfortable way to access the daily SQL Server backups.

I want to do some asp.net coding using Visual Studio 2012, and I do not want to install SQL Server on my machine since it is too heavy and slowing down the system.

I see that you can add `.mdf` file to a project and use it as a standard database:

- is it possible to do the same with SQL Server backup?
- is it possible to extract `.mdf` file from SQL Server backup without SQL Server?

Thank you in advance,
M.

Comment: Have you thought about installing the Express edition of SQL?

Comment: **No**, you cannot directly "link" to a `.bak` file. And **no**, you cannot use a `.mdf` without installing SQL Server - even if you use the `.mdf` "directly" from Visual Studio, you **must have** SQL Server Express installed.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is one programs runs only in service mode, so you need to have it's server running to gain it's services. The answer is NO, but you can use SQL Server Express or other stuff.

After you had a server running, you can use SQL Assembly to access `.mdf` file directly, not bu addressing server. You will need to create a connection string like :

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

And put `mydbfile.mdf` into the `Data` directory.